# How to add Optional Sequence

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments

**Note:** This question could be a duplicate but I couldn't find any so far.

It is known that `Optional` (:) can be use to represent expression if omitted.

```
f[x_, y_:0]:= {x, y};
f[a]
(*{a,0}*)
```

Now what should I do so that I can use a sequence of values in the `Optional`, something like this:

`f[x_, y_(if omitted gives sequence of 1,2,3)]:= {x, y};`

so that If I evaluate `f[a]` I get `{a,1,2,3}.`

The method `f[x_, y_: Sequence[1, 2, 3]] := {x, y}`  will not work because of the evaluation that happens at the time of defining `f`.

Of course this can be solved by giving `HoldAll` Attributes to the function `f`:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[x_, y_: Sequence[1, 2, 3]] := {x, y}

f[a]

(*{a, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

But this needs to set the attributes which some times is not desired.

**Question:**

Is there a way to add sequence as Optional without the need to use Attributes?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to get for `f[1,3,4]`?

Comment: @Kuba, Perhaps I should have used `f[x_,y__:options]` instead of `f[x_,y_:options]`. Basically I am designing  a graphical function which takes default styles if nothing inputted. After all, I think this approach is not the best way to do that because if I have more than one default style and I need to change only one I need then to input all of the default including the new one. May be I need to use `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue`

Comment: I see, you can put styles in a `Directive`.

Comment: Yes I could but again if I want to change only one style then I need to input all others in `Directive` otherwise the inputted style will be the only one will pass to RHS. For example, `f[x_, y_: Directive[style1, 
    style2]]` if I want to change `style2` I need to do it like this `f[
  firstinput, Directive[style1, newstyle]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Default` is another way to specify optional arguments, which allows for this:

```
Default[f, 2] = Sequence[1, 2, 3]
f[x_, y_.] := {x, y}
f[1, 2]
```

> `{1, 2}`

```
f[1]
```

> `{1, 1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_, y_] := {x, y}
f[x_] := {x, Sequence[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Probably `f[x_] := {x,1,2,3}` would be easier :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [C.E](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) great answer, the specific answer to this question is something like this:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_, y_: Hold[1, 2, 3]] := {x, ReleaseHold@ y}
f[a, 2 + 3]
(*{w,5}*)
f[a]
(*{a, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the canonical way to solve evaluation issues inside of a function definition is a judicious use of [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern):

```
f[x_, HoldPattern[y_:Sequence[1, 2, 3]]] := {x, y}

f[x]
```

> {x, 1, 2, 3}